# Is there any way to convert sum into product?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was wondering whether there was a way to convert a sum into a product for example: $a+b=10$ into $ab$ or $a^2$.

So say if I had $a+b=10$, is there any way to convert that into either $ab$ or $a^2$. If anyone has got answer please let me know and provide a proof if you can!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, I'm voting to close this question  because it's too vague. What do you mean by "convert a sum to a product"? Why would you want to? You _might_ be thinking about something like this rule for exponents: $2^{a+b} = 2^a 2^b$.

Comment: If you know $(a-b)$, then you can use $(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2=4ab$

Answer (score 1):

You would probably get better answers if you explain your motivation for doing such a conversion.

In general, there is no way to convert an equation of the form $a+b=\cdots$ to one of the form $ab=\cdots$ because they are not equivalent. For instance, $a+b=10$ has solutions $a=1, b=9$ or $a=5, b=5$ (just to name two, there are many others). For the first solution we have $ab=1\cdot 9=9$, while for the second we have $ab = 5\cdot 5 = 25$. So placing a restriction on the **sum** of $a$ and $b$ is not equivalent to placing a restriction on their **product**.

From the equation $a+b=10$ you could square both sides and get $(a+b)^2=10^2$, or $a^2+2ab+b^2=100$, which implies $ab = \frac{1}{2}(100-a^2-b^2)$. However, by squaring the equation we have introduced new solutions (you can check that $a=-12, b=2$ satisfies the new equation, but not the original one).

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite vague but it is quite difficult considering you only have the sum in terms of $2$ variables with one equation.

Still, with your example we have $a+b=10$ so $a=10-b$ so then $a^2=(10-b)^2$ which you can expand. But without another equation in terms of $a,b$ we cannot get any numerical values without just rearranging!

Comment: Hi I want to change sum to product for e.g. a+b=any real number into a^2, a×b=any numbers

Comment: Yes it is possible, but look at @kccu answer, if we have $a+b=$ a real number then are often lots of possibilities!